# How do I prevent googleVis from shortening labels?

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I have some googleVis charts in a shiny app, but googleVis shorten the label on the horizontal axis by default when they are too long. How do I prevent this behavior? The example below replicates the behavior I would like to prevent:

```
df=data.frame(country=c(paste(rep("very very long label", 1e+2)), "GB", "BR"), 
              val1=c(10,13,14), 
              val2=c(23,12,32))
Line <- gvisLineChart(df)
plot(Line)
```

The link to the documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

Comment: there are [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for both overall `height` and `chartArea.height` -- recommend setting both, reducing `chartArea.height` until fully displayed -- also check `hAxis.slantedText` & `hAxis.slantedTextAngle` as well...

Answer (score 3):

That's always a tricky thing, if you ask Google the same question. But I found one 'trick' to show the x-labels, here my workaround:

Change the chart area: the upper "padding" taking space from the hAxis below.
This is possible in R with the `options` parameter in the `gvisLineChart()` function.

```
Line <- gvisLineChart(df,
    options = list(chartArea = 
 "{'width': '82%', height: '60%', top: '9%', right: '3%', bottom: '90'}"))

plot(Line)
```

Of course you have to adjust the values to your needs. Perhaps this approach helps you.

Comment: I am trying to tweak my charts following your suggestion but I cannot figure out why changing `height` does not affect the area of the charts (meaning the plane where the bars are displayed). Any suggestions?